# Payment method sort order. Won't work

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-1.5

I'm trying to change my payment method sort order but it won't work.

I have 2 payment method modules, and i need select the output order, already changed  on config.xml of each module.

But don't change the order. I've try to change the call of phtml, to getChildHtml('payment',true,true); but neither work too.

I'm out of ideas, someone can help me??

Thanks guys.

Comment: you probable have sort order specified in the admin panel under the System/Configuration/Payment Methods section. These setting have priority over the .xml config ones.

Comment: @SlayerBirden thks for comment, but isn't it becouse i'ts my custom payment module, so i don't make anything to controll this.

Comment: @SlayerBirden ty so mutch, you'r right at all. i don't  have the order on my payment modules, so i put it and work. ty